# Reverse regexp in checkstyle

Tags: android, regex, reverse, checkstyle

I’m trying to add a checkstyle, which will limit number of symbols in android string resource. I’m using RegexpSingleLine (also tried with Regexp), and already have a regexp expression. Now the problem is that it asserts when number of symbols in string is in range, but I need to assert in opposite case, when the number is outside of the range. So I need to reverse the expression somehow (or maybe use some property). Could someone help?
Here's my check.

```
<module name="RegexpSingleline">
        <property name="fileExtensions" value="xml"/>
        <property name="format" value='^\s*&lt;string\s*name="string_name"&gt;(.{5,10})&lt;'/>
</module>
```

Comment: Try `value='^\s*&lt;string\s*name="string_name"&gt;([^&lt;]{0,4}|[^&lt;]{11,})&lt;'`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried, but now it just accepts everything :)

Comment: If you copied/pasted the regex from the comment, it may contain garbled chars. Try from [here](https://regex101.com/r/BV1Of1/1)

Comment: Maybe you need to match anything but the pattern above? Try [`^(?!\s*&lt;string\s*name="string_name"&gt;.{5,10}&lt;).*`](https://regex101.com/r/BV1Of1/3).

Comment: It seems that your regex checks that the string length is 0-4 or more than 11 characters. So could you just check if it's 5-10 characters? [example](https://regex101.com/r/BV1Of1/4)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Both of the options you're suggesting work when I check them online, but not in case of checkstyle. I'm trying to set min and max limits, but haven't had that working yet.

Comment: @ThomasJensen Your solution was almost like I had in my question, and  it's again working correctly in online checker, but checkstyle asserts when symbols count is inside 5-10 range, so I need to reverse condition so it asserts when count is outside of the range.

Comment: Maybe because `\s` must be written as `\\s`? Or just `[ \t]` instead of `\s`?

Comment: Changing `\s` to `\\s` doesn't help also. But I noticed that the expression which is in the beginning works, ex. in here `[^&lt;]{0,4}|‌​[^&lt;]{11,}` if I put `[^&lt;]{0,4}` part works, but `[^&lt;]{11,}` doesn't. So I put `[^&lt;]{11,}` in the beginning and now I'm trying to make the regex to fail if there isn't at least one character (in other words set min limit to 1). At the moment I have this expression.
`value='^\s*&lt;string\s*name="string_name"&gt;([^&lt;]{11,})'`

Comment: That does not make much sense, as if the `|` alternation did not work though if you are using `\s`, the `|` must work. `value='^\s*&lt;string\s*name="string_name"&gt;([^&lt;]{11,}|[^&lt;]{0,4})‌'` should work too (to match 0 to 4 chars other than `<`). Again, do not copy/paste from comments, since there are some invisible chars SO inserts for better looks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume from your question that you want to flag Strings that are not 5-10 characters in length. With Checkstyle, you must find a regular expression which does that. There is no "invert" option for this check.

This should do it ([explanation](https://regex101.com/r/BV1Of1/5)):

```xml
<module name="RegexpSingleline">
    <property name="fileExtensions" value="xml"/>
    <property name="format"
        value='^\s*&lt;string\s*name="string_name"&gt;(?![^&lt;]{5,10}&lt;)([^&lt;].*?)&lt;'/>
</module>
```

The above will not match empty strings. If you need to flag empty Strings as well, use this ([explanation](https://regex101.com/r/D0ZWpF/1)):

```xml
<module name="RegexpSingleline">
    <property name="fileExtensions" value="xml"/>
    <property name="format"
        value='^\s*&lt;string\s*name="string_name"&gt;(?:&lt;|(?![^&lt;]{5,10}&lt;)([^&lt;].*?)&lt;)'/>
</module>
```

Comment: Finally! This works as I wanted. Thank you for your help. Also is that possible to ignore escape character in the string?

Comment: I would guess that's possible, too, but it requires some fiddling with a still more complex regex. You can ask that as a new question, though.